# Nodejs- console.error vs util.debug

Tags: node.js

I noticed that node.js has both `console.error` and `util.debug`, as well as `console.log` and `util.log`.

Is there a difference besides the console.* functions being more robust in the parameters they take?  The API says that they write to stdout and stderr respectively.

If there's no difference, which should I use and why?

Comment: For completeness:  [here is the doc for the console.* functions](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/all.html#console.log), and [here is the doc for the util.* functions](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/all.html#util).  Note that `console.*` supports parameter replacement via format string, while `util.*` prepends a prefix (timestamp()/"DEBUG") before output is written.  Both sets of funcs use the underlying `process.stdout` (for `.log()`), and `process.stderr` (for `.warn()` and `.debug()`).  Note that all operations on `.stderr` are synchronous, while operations on `stdout` are async.

Comment: to me, the big differences are 1) `util.debug()` and `util.error()` go to `stderr`, whereas the other to `stdio`, and 2) the `util` funcs are synchronous (blocking).

Comment: correction, `util` funcs except `util.log()` are synchronous

Answer (score 58, accepted):

They're two different functions, that do two different things. Learn to read the source. It will help you a lot (even in languages like C# with reflector)

## Sources

### Console

> https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js

```
Console.prototype.warn = function() {
  this._stderr.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};

Console.prototype.error = Console.prototype.warn;
```

### Utils

> https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js

```
exports.debug = function(x) {
  process.stderr.write('DEBUG: ' + x + '\n');
};
```

## Log Functions:

### Console

```
exports.log = function() {
  process.stdout.write(format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

### Utils

```
exports.log = function(msg) {
  exports.puts(timestamp() + ' - ' + msg.toString());
};
exports.puts = function() {
  for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
    process.stdout.write(arguments[i] + '\n');
  }
};
```

## Why

As with every other Unix oriented system, which node is most definitely geared in the guise of - see the many comments from Ryan on the topic, the logging functions are given in the same guise. There are two basic classes for logging, and they both do effectively the same thing, but for different reasons. To the casual observer, they are the same, but they're not really.

**Console logging** is intended to be used during debugging. This will go to STDOUT and will show your statements on the REPL<sup>1</sup> console, useful for debugging.

**Utility logging** is intended to be used during standard services runtime. They will goto the ***process*** STDOUT, which often is a log file for the process.

But since this can be outwardly overridden at need, and because it will be different in the future (most likely) for Windows processes (given the new ports and developments) and other systems, then you should try to use these methods as ***the de facto way to write out to the logs during normal runtime***. Examples of how it will be different in Windows include the use of the system log for logging, as opposed to a straight logfile.

### So how do you know which one you need?

If you're planning on running this in the REPL for debugging, use the console logger. If you're intending to start the service and forget about it, then use the utils logging.

<sub><sup>1</sup> – Read Evaluate Print Loop</sub>

Comment: So it seems that the `util` functions add some extra info. Do you know if it's generally advised to use one or the other? If so, when should I use the other?

Comment: This answer is long and not entirely clear.  It's also not entirely correct, as the code has changed.  The two functions are *both* going to the "process" stdio, and in both cases can be either sent to the terminal or to a log file.  The only difference I can see comes down to formatting.  The util.* functions have a set format and just iterate on your arguments, where the console.* functions accept a string and a string format.

Comment: at the point in time it was written they went to two different places. Someone else edited with updates based on where they were now updated. I was mostly trying to indicate that there was source to be referred to and that there was no API in a toddler language that hadn't even passed the 0.5 stage (if memory serves me of July 2011) and was nowhere near to 1.0

Comment: @DanDascalescu would you in the future kindly notate in a comment that you edited the question and fundamentally changed the code that was originally given because the underlying node code updated?

Comment: @jcolebrand: sure. SO should notify the OP of edits, I think, even if users with more than 2K rep make them. I get suggested edit notifications from users under 2K.

Comment: I meant _in_ the post, as I got the notification for that ;-) ~~ In this case you altered what had been a snip from the documentation, but future readers may not know how to view revisions, etc.

Comment: FYI: utils.print, .puts, .debug, and .error are now all deprecated. console.log is advised instead of .print and .puts, and console.error is advised instead of .debug and .error. See the utils code.

Comment: Hi @JoeLapp thanks for the update, but you may want to update the answer and edit it since when I wrote this over 3 years ago it was a verbatim dump from the source, and the product was very young.

Answer (score 14):

Joe Lapp's comment to the currently accepted answer deserves to be raised as an answer:

> FYI: utils.print, .puts, .debug, and .error are now all deprecated. console.log is advised instead of .print and .puts, and console.error is advised instead of .debug and .error. See the utils code

References:

[The Node.js Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_debug_string)

[The current utils code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d394e9e6bb75dc6a15befb89f7cd0b30df51596f/lib/util.js#L791-L814)

Answer (score 1):

The console methods are more robust in that you can pass n arguments and they will be concatenated before being written to stdout or stderr, but they are both convenience wrappers around the same underlying calls to stdout and stderr.

.log, .info, and .dir are non blocking.
.warn and .error are blocking.

console.log and util.log both write using process.stdout.write. console.error and util.debug both write using process.binding("stdio").writeError.